# Comment form via composer for Laravel

Tags: forms, composer-php, comments

How can I add simple comment form with a smile for my Laravel project via composer?
I would like to add it to my Laravel project like FCKEditor https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor.
I don't sure that I can find it via packagist.org.

Answer (score 0):

I will use this code, it doesn't have smiles, but it look like good https://github.com/actuallymab/laravel-comment